# Concatenation does not work when linked server used SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, linked-server

When running a select statement in a SQL Server (**server1**)

```
select IDNo, Code + ' ' + No + ' ' + Extension as Ext, MenuNo
from [database1].[dbo].[table1]
```

gives result as expected:

```
1  |  Toranto 56 Placid 47  |  34563
```

But From another server(server2)  the same query with server1 as linked server, gives output incompletely. ie
Concatenated column(2nd Column) only return first letter of the expected column value (`IDNo` and  `MenuNo` coming correctly)

Query with **linked server** (run on **server2**):

```
select IDNo, Code+' '+ No + ' ' + Extension, MenuNo
from [server1].[database1].[dbo].[table1]
```

Output:

```
 1  |  T  |  34563
```

**Note:**

- `server2 : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
- `server1:  Latin1_General_CI_AI`

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CAST

```
select IDNo, CAST(Code+' '+ No + ' ' + Extension) as VARCHAR(8000), MenuNo from [server1].[database1].[dbo].[table1]
```

or  RESULT SET

```
EXEC('SELECT ... ') WITH RESULT SET ...
```

Comment: Thanks . it worked. Is it something to do with collation ?

Comment: @ Is it something to do with collation@ No.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about different `Collations`.

Here you can read what it is :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017

Here you can read what to do if `Collations` differs between servers :

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic906390-146-1.aspx

(you must complete your query, indicate which `Collations` you want to use)

For example :

```
SELECT Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2
FROM LinkedServer.db1.owner.Table1 AS Table1
JOIN db2.owner.Table2 AS Table2 
ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on SO. You'd be better including the relevant parts of the links to provide a comprehensive answer, and avoid yours being deleted.